# Forma correta de gravar vários registros de uma vez dbgrid e clientdataset

Tags: mysql, delphi-xe5

Eu tenho que gravar vários registros de uma vez no banco, estou utilizando da forma abaixo, porém eu acho que dar applyupdate a cada interação não é a forma correta. Existe outra forma?

```
procedure TFrm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
i: Integer;
begin
  (ds.DataSet as TClientdataset).Open;
  For i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    (ds.DataSet as TClientdataset).Insert;
    ds.DataSet.FieldByName('med1').AsInteger:= 1;
    ds.DataSet.FieldByName('med2').AsInteger:= 1;
    ds.DataSet.FieldByName('med3').AsInteger:= 2;
    ds.DataSet.FieldByName('med4').AsDateTime:= Now;
    ds.DataSet.FieldByName('med5').AsFloat:= 1;
    ds.DataSet.FieldByName('med6').AsDateTime:= Now;
    (ds.DataSet as TClientdataset).Post;
    (ds.DataSet as TClientdataset).ApplyUpdates(0);
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente lembre-se que o `ApplyUpdates` só funciona quando você está trabalhando com `CachedUpdates` (marcado como `true` nas propriedades da conexão).

Acredito que a melhor maneira de utilizar o `ApplyUpdates` é esta, e tratando possíveis problemas que possam ocorrer através do retorno que a própria variável lhe retorna.

Segundo a documentação do Embarcadero, o retorno da função é do tipo `Integer` indicando a quantidade de erros que ocorreram, e assim você pode conseguir identificar quando ocorreu um erro e tentar ter a menor perda possível de informações que serão enviadas ao banco de dados.

Assim sendo, acredito que esta é a maneira mais correta de utilizar esta função.

Maiores informações:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates